# Sum columns of array subject to mask

Tags: python, pandas, stacked-chart

I have a df[n,f] eg,n rows x 35 features.  The sum of all the features across each row is = 1.0.   I am attempting to create a stacked bar chart by grouping all features which are not above a certain minimum average into a category "All Others."  I am attempting to use a mask to accomplish this.  Eg,  if I set a threshold of 5%:

```
[In]
mask = (df.sum(axis = 0) > num_selected * 0.05).values
mask

[Out]
array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
    True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

My question is: given this mask, how can I group all the features which do not meet the criteria (eg, are 'false') into "All Others" and use that to create a stacked bar chart with all the other 'True' features?

Comment: IIUC you can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for this

Comment: @EdChum - Not clear to me how this would work, Ed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a NumPy ndarray, you can use fancy indexing methods, i.e.

```
import numpy as np

df = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10,35))
mask = df.sum(axis=0) > 500

trueFeatures = df[:,~mask]
allOthers = df[:,mask]

print mask
print trueFeatures
print allOthers
```

gives the following output :

```
[ True False  True  True  True False False  True False False False False
 False  True  True False False False  True  True False  True False  True
  True False  True  True False False  True  True  True  True  True]
[[39 52 37 70 50 43 94 13 88  2 20 52 26  0 31 38]
 [40 25  9 26 64 34 22 35  0 28 15 60 49 58 74 99]
 [84 24  4 46 26 42 60 39 54 46 85 87 37 72 22 54]
 [59 34 47 29 20 91 11 36 39 43 72 76 46 47 51 36]
 [38 82 30 39 54 21 19 35 61 80 69 38 25 97 36 77]
 [15 50 43  3  1  3 75 36  1 40 46 19 61 24 40 34]
 [47 92 70 23 37  1  3 95 34 93 10 23 11 14 68  2]
 [70  2 60 94 63 92 34  6 15 71  2 30 82 59 63  5]
 [94 33 77 86 12  4 69  9 31 42 30 23 35 17  8  5]
 [ 4 75 19 73 27 79 87 69 59 55 54 71 31 50 54 86]]
[[83 11 19 58 20 41 71 36 73 91 91 30 60 48 83 30 78 27 86]
 [46 67 81 62 75 88 71 33 23 71 79 52 18 33 72 89 54 50 99]
 [80  4 59 82 45 99 71 38 99 83 36 51  3 88 84 87 69 55 50]
 [62 34 53 77  3 79 74 27 77 28 85 82 87 13 96 60 69 13 99]
 [90 83 51 10 94 14 31 45  9 98 43 40 66 92 13  3 52 76 55]
 [99 73 50 97 41 34 90 63 97 73 58 14 92 25 94 43 74 71 65]
 [ 8  5 33 86 98 96 81 94 84 65 32 18 47 48 64 17 74 53 68]
 [18 84 50  9 61 55 65 72 26 37 24 91 87 81 97  1 36 38 93]
 [45 97 96 76 18  5  1 95 32 33 40 86 39 37 41 80  2 74 80]
 [64 75 10 63 96 44 44 86 32 99 53 57 91 37 87 91 65 64 62]]
```

which, in my understanding of the problem, answers your question :)

Comment: not sure how to apply this suggestion to the problem above.   First of all - does your suggestion select the columns in the hypothetical array you suggest?    Or would I do array[:,mask] which doesn't seem to work?

Comment: many thanks, this is a bit clearer.  However, I still need more help - I'd like to use a dataframe to create a stacked bar graph.   To do this, I'll need to select the column names corresponding to the 'True' elements of the array and append 'all others' which reflect the new column.

Answer (score 1):

With "Le Petit Prince's" help I solved the problem.  Posting it for those who might want to make it more 'pythoneseque.'  In particular, I note my method for selecting the list items could probably be improved.  Note df["Asset Type"] is a feature which serves as the labels.

```
import pylab
num_selected = 20

# Create an array with the n highest elements of the ordered portfolio
x_range = np.arange(0,num_selected)
test = df[n,f]

# create a mask to choose features which are at least 5% of the portfolio
mask = np.sum(test,axis = 0) > num_selected* 0.05

# output will be two arrays concatenated. 
others = np.sum(test[:,~mask],axis = 1).reshape(num_selected,1)
primary = test[:,mask]

# Create legend which is is defined as a subset of all asset types
graph_legend = list(df['Asset Type'])
new_legend = []
for i in range(0, len(graph_legend)):
    if mask[i] == True:
        new_legend.append(graph_legend[i])
new_legend.append('All Others')

#create output dataframe with feature labels determined by mask. 
output = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((primary, others),axis =1),columns = new_legend)

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.ylabel('Composition')
plt.xlabel('Top Portfolios')
plt.title('Portfolio Composition, Top %d Portfolios, >  %.0f%% Capital' % (num_selected,8))

output.plot(kind='bar', stacked= True, figsize=(12,9),ax=ax)
```